# how do i keep adding number using for-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I add number whenever user key in something? (using for-loop)

```
example:
empty= []
counter= 0
food = input("What is your favourite food?")

if user enter something in the food input then +1.
output: empty=1

after exiting the program, when the user enters something in the food input again then it will +1 again

output empty = 2
```

Should I use a for-loop for this? and how?

Comment: If you need to remember information (like the value of `counter`) between executions of a program, you need to store it outside of the program, typically a file or a database.  You will also need to be able to *read* from there at the start of the program.

Comment: Are you asking how to ask the user several time within the same run of the program or do you want to save information between different runs?

If you want to save between different runs I would suggest looking at the python module named configparser for small examples like this.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Since you want to read the counter every time a new instance of the program is created, you need to store it in some external source i.e. some file or database. You can use basic file handling or SQLite.

The following should get you started with SQLite.

```
import sqlite3

database_path = "test.db"
init_query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS food (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT NOT NULL);"
insert_query = "INSERT INTO food ('name') values ('{food_name}');"
count_query = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM food;"

count = 0

conn = sqlite3.connect(database_path)

with conn:

    # Initialize DB if it hasn't been created already.
    conn.execute(init_query)
    conn.commit()

    # Get count of all the food items entered.
    count_result = conn.execute(count_query)
    if count_result:
        counter = count_result.fetchone()[0]
        print("Counter: {}".format(counter))

    food = input("What is your favorite food?")

    if food:
        formatted_insert_query = insert_query.format(food_name=food)
        conn.execute(formatted_insert_query)
        conn.commit()
```

Comment: The `counter` is not saved when user exits the program.

Comment: Updated the answer for SQLite. This way you can also track the food items the user enters. You can try your hand at file handling which will have you read counter from file before execution and if user enters something, write it to that file.